# Data Validation inside a function - Python

Tags: python, function, csv, datetime, validation

I am running into an issue with validating an input is a valid date, and if not coming back to the question for a retry.
I want to loop through this header and ask for input for each item.

```
header = [employee_id,name,address,ssn,date_of_birth,job_title,start_date,end_date]
```

The CSV is empty aside from the header, as I am appending these rows into via this program. I want the date_validator() to work for DOB, start_date and end_date, but so far i can get it to validate that the input is wrong, it just doesnt go back and ask for the input again.
Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

```
import csv
import datetime

def add_employee():
    global date_answer
    list = []
    for i in range(len(header)):
        var = header[i]
        answer1 = input('Input Employees {}:'.format(var))
        if "date" in header[i]:
            date_answer = answer1
            date_validater()
        list.append(answer1)
    with open('employees.csv','a',newline="") as f_object:
        writer = csv.writer(f_object)
        writer.writerow(list)
        f_object.close()
    print()

def date_validater():
    # input date
    date_string = date_answer
    date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'
    try:
        dateObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
        print(dateObject)
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect data format, should be MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple hints:

1. Functions take parameters...
2. Globals are a terrible ideas most of the time. Avoid like the plague.

Pass the variables to the function to use it inside the function.

```py
import csv
import datetime

def add_employee(header):
    list = []
    for i in range(len(header)):
        var = header[i]
        answer1 = input('Input Employees {}:'.format(var))
        if "date" in header[i]:
            date_validater(answer1)
        list.append(answer1)
    with open('employees.csv','a',newline="") as f_object:
        writer = csv.writer(f_object)
        writer.writerow(list)
        f_object.close()
    print()

def date_validater(date_string):
    # input date
    date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'
    try:
        dateObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
        print(dateObject)
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect data format, should be MM/DD/YYYY")
```

or something like that...

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I incorporated this, and it flags the incorrect format but still moves on to the next question instead of re-asking. any ideas?

Comment: ah if that's the new issue, then you need to use a while loop to repeat the question until the validation is correct, so your validate function should return True or False and your loop on each question should loop until the validation function return is True.